# Delta filter stops working for Microsoft Graph email - Microsoft Resolution

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

**Microsoft has resolved this.**

For years we have been using the Microsoft Graph API. Over the weekend, something changed, so that when making this GET:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/Inbox/messages/delta?filter=receivedDateTime+ge+2022-09-23`

the result is:

```
`400 Bad Request`
```

and the response is:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQuery","message":"The '$filter' parameter value is not supported for 'Messages' resource; only a value of 'receivedDateTime ge value' is supported."}}
```

I have reported the issue, and Microsoft is working on it:
['$filter=receivedDateTime+ge+{value}' stops working](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/18636#issuecomment-1259766134)

User fasterforward noted that the messages/delta is not working but that messages url without the delta is working:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime desc&$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2022-09-27
```

This works for me.

I am unable to post comments or answers, so I hope posting this detail helps someone else especially @lazyden, @keithadams, @Joyce, @Jamie Dan, @Ram Prasad, @SBE

Comment: I'm puzzled why there's `+` in the endpoint. But the `+` really appeared in [the api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#odata-query-parameters), but I think the endpoint should have it and should look like  `delta?filter=receivedDateTime ge {value}`. Could you pls try it? I don't have test source.

Comment: Thanks @TinyWang. Same result using space or +. At the issue URL, fasterforward mentioned that the messages endpoint without the delta is still working, so I tested this, and it worked, but I still need the delta.

Comment: Microsoft resolution [https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/18636#issuecomment-1262909767](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/18636#issuecomment-1262909767)

Comment: @SBE Microsoft has resolved this

Comment: @lazyden Microsoft has resolved this